# How to add controls dynamically and manage views accordingly in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a few dropdowns in a `UIScrollView`. I want to generate a `UITextField` dynamically based on a specific value selected in a drop down. The textfield has to be generated right below the drop down and all the other controls following the drop down has to be shifted down to make way for the new `UITextField` when added and shift up when the new `textfield` disappear.

Comment: Start learning [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to make a drop down is using **UITableVIew** where you can resize it, resize the content an so on, and of course make your own customised cells

Comment: Is there anything similar to stack panel(windows) in iOS where views are managed by its own when controls are generated and disappears dynamically?

Comment: You can use the **UITableView**, try [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/) maybe you will find this useful